# Проверка на время

Tags: php, sql, время

Нужно сделать следующее:

> Если есть > 3 записей, которым меньше часа, то выводить 1, если нет - 0.

Мой код работает криво, хотелось бы узнать, что не так:

```
  $timeLimit = time() - (1 * 60);

  $q = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `logs` WHERE `time` < $timeLimit");
  $n = $db->num($q);

  return $n > 3 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

`WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > ltime;`

Comment: $db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `logs` WHERE `ltime` < $timeLimit");
так не пробовали делать? тогда сразу в q должно вернуться количество.
И да, кстати, что именно кривого? не считает? всегда 0 выводит? или вообще ошибку в sql дает?

Comment: я бы еще limit 4 поставил, чтобы не тащить лишние записи, раз вам только да/нет надо

Comment: @luxor, ааааа, тупанул! У почему-то за час всял 1, а не 60. Оформите свой ответ и помечу его!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И да, еще. не сразу заметил. time() возвращает количество секунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1970 года. А вы просто отнимаете от текущего времени минуту. Нужно отнять час и проверить, не меньше ли стало $timelimit чем ltime.

PS Оформил :)

Comment: @luxor, отлично, пометил :)